# Convert nested array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arguments

I am looking for a solution, to push/convert array items into a object back, without using keys?

```
function pleaseBuy(){
    var args = arguments;
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; ++i) {
        args += args[i];
    };
};

function getList(){
   return ["pepsi","cola","7up"];
}

var list = ({ favorite: "drpepper"}, getList())
pleaseBuy(list)
```

Expected result:

```
args = ({ favorite: "drpepper"}, "pepsi", "cola", "7up")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the `pleaseBuy` function, I'd say:

```
function getList(){
   return ["pepsi","cola","7up"];
}

var list = getList().concat( { favorite: "drpepper" } );
//                                     ^ NB should be :
// or favorite first
var list = [{ favorite: "drpepper" }].concat(getList());
/* 
   list now contains:
   ['pepsi, 'cola','7up',{ favorite: "drpepper" }]
*/
```

An object allways contains key-value pairs. If you want to convert an array to an object, you'll thus have to assign keys and values. For example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,'some'], arr2Obj = {};
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i=i+1){
   arr2Obj[arr[i]] = i;
}

/* 
   arr2Obj now contains:
   { 
     1: 0,
     2: 1,
     3: 2,
     4: 3,
     some: 4
   }
*/
```

Other example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,'some'], arr2Numbers = {};
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i=i+1){
       arr2Numbers[arr[i]] = !isNaN(Number(arr[i]));
}
/* 
   arr2Numbers now contains:
   { 
     1: true,
     2: true,
     3: true,
     4: true,
     some: false
   }
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the javascript [push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) function?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.unshift()` <sup>docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to prepend to an array.

```
var list = getList();
list.unshift( { favorite="drpepper"});

// [{ favorite="drpepper"}, "pepsi", "cola", "7up"]
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Ds9y5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array = ["pepsi","cola","7up"];
array.push({ favorite: "drpepper"});
```

Or

```
var array2 = ["pepsi","cola","7up"];
var array = [{favorite: "drpepper"}];
for(var ctr = 0 ; ctr < array2.length ; ctr++){
  array.push(array2[ctr]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = getList();
s.unshift({ favorite : "drpepper"}); // at the first place in array
s.push({ favorite : "drpepper"}); // at the last place in array
alert(s);
```

[JavaScript push() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
[JavaScript unshift() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)